# Why do my environment variables get reset after setting them with gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp, environment-variables

I'm setting environment variables during the build process using Gulp, but once my app starts those env vars are blank.

*gulpfile.js*

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
  if (fileExists('.env.json')) {
    console.log('Setting environment variables');
    env({
      file: '.env.json',
      vars: {"DB_NAME": "nbadbtest"}
    });
    console.log("DB_NAME=%s", process.env.DB_NAME); // DB_NAME=TestDB
  } else {
    console.log('.env.json file not found. Not setting environment variables.')
  }
  var tsProject = ts.createProject(path.resolve('./tsconfig.json'));
  var tsResult = tsProject.src().pipe(ts(tsProject));
  return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})
```

After running env() in my gulp task, I can see that process.env.DB_NAME is set to "TestDB".

*server.ts*

`console.log("DB_NAME=%s", process.env.DB_NAME); // DB_NAME=undefined`

Immediately after my imports in server.ts, I log the env var again, but this time it's undefined.

Here's the output in terminal:

> [22:06:28] Starting 'build'...
>   Setting environment variables
>   DB_NAME=nbadbtest
>   [22:06:32] Finished 'build' after 3.26 s
>   > node dist/server.js
>
> DB_NAME=undefined

Comment: FYI, I'm working with Visual Studio Code in Mac OS X El Capitan v10.11.6

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is due to the terminal window that starts up the node application being already open before the environment variables are set.  When I run `npm start`, I have a "prestart" npm script that fires off my build task in gulp, which sets those environment variables.  So `gulp build` and `node dist/server.js` are run in the same terminal window.

Running `gulp build` and then opening up a new terminal window to run `node dist/server.js` fixes this issue because the new terminal window has access to the environment variables that were set.

Instead of setting my environment variables via gulp, I'm now using dotenv.  I just create a .env file with all my environment variables and configure dotenv in my server.js file like so:

`require('dotenv').config();`